# How can I combine elements at the same index from separate lists?

Tags: java, list, loops, merge

I am trying to combine multiple String lists.

Say I have two (could be more) lists of the same size:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1One","1Two","1Three");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("2One","2Two","2Three");
```

I want to combine the value of the corresponding indexes and place them into a new list:

```
List3 = new {"1One2One", "1Two2Two", "1Three2Three"};
```

Currently I have a list of 2 objects, each object contains the list that I want to combine the elements within.

So I want to combine element 1 in the list from object 1 with element 1 from the list from object 2.

This is what I have attempted:

```
public void generateFileList(List<Object> cl){


    int count = 0;
    String temp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < cl.size(); i++){

        for (int x = 0; x < cl.get(i).getItemList().size(); x++) {
            if (count == x){
                temp += cl.get(i).getListItem(x);
                break;
            }

        }
        count++;
        textList.add(temp);

    }
}
public void test(){
    for(String s : textList){
        System.out.println("List Element -  " + s);
    }
    System.out.println(textList.size());
}
```

Which prints out:

```
List Element - 1One
List Element - 1One1Three
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code doesn't match up with the description.  Where is `list1` and `list2`?  why aren't they used in the `generatedFileList` method

Comment: Your whole algorithm is wrong.

Comment: Are you working with a 2D list or 2 lists?  Something doesn't match up in your code vs what you're asking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code you have won't compile. It should be:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1One","1Two","1Three");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("2One","2Two","2Three");
```

Next, it is best to use an `Iterator` than access a `List` by index:

```
public List<String> concat(final List<String> list1, final List<String> list2) {
    final Iterator<String> i1 = list1.iterator();
    final Iterator<String> i2 = list2.iterator();

    final List<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
    while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
        combined.add(i1.next() + i2.next());
    }
    return combined;
}
```

For an arbitrary number of `List`:

```
public List<String> concat(final List<String>... lists) {
    final List<Iterator<String>> it = new LinkedList<>();
    for (List<String> l : lists) {
        it.add(l.iterator());
    }

    final List<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
    outer:
    while (true) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Iterator<String> i : it) {
            if (!i.hasNext()) {
                break outer;
            }
            sb.append(i.next());
        }
        combined.add(sb.toString());
    }
    for (final Iterator<String> i : it) {
        if (i.hasNext()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lists not the same length.");
        }
    }
    return combined;
}
```

Comment: What if I have more than two objects?

Comment: You said specifically had `2`. Now you are changing the question?

Comment: I think he has some sort of list of objects where each object contains 2 lists...not very clear...

Comment: @crm added an example for an arbitrary number of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists have the same size, just have a for loop from 0 to list size, and add in the new list the concatenation of the elements from the same position in the two lists, like for (int i =0; i< list1.size(); i++) { resultedlist.add(list1.get(i) + list2.get(i))}

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the 2 lists are the same size:

```
List<String> list1 = new {"1One","1Two","1Three"};
List<String> list2 = new {"2One","2Two","2Three"};
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    list3.add(list1.get(i) + list2.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Accessing a `List` by index is a terrible idea. Moreover, the code you have copy-pasted doesn't compile.

Comment: yes, had an assignment typo.  Why is accessing a `List` by index a bad idea?

Comment: What if I have more than 2 objects?

Comment: You could either put this loop inside whatever loop provided the "pair" of lists, or just turn it into a function and call it for each pair of lists.

Comment: Accessing by index on a `LinkedList` is `O(n)` - this makes the algorithm `O(n ^ 2)`. It is generally a bad idea to access by index unless you can guarantee the type of `List`.